# PHP multiple checkbox array with different values - Get total price of checked checkboxes

Tags: php, sum

HTML Code

```
0<input type="checkbox" name="count[]" id="count[]" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="language[]" id="language" value="C++"/>C++ 
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" id="price" value="700"> <br/>

1<input type="checkbox" name="count[]" id="count[]" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" name="language[]" id="language" value="Assembler"/>Assembler 
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" id="price" value="600"><br/>

2<input type="checkbox" name="count[]" id="count[]" value="2"/>
<input type="hidden" name="language[]" id="language" value="Java"/>Java 
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" id="price" value="500"> <br/>

3<input type="checkbox" name="count[]" id="count[]" value="3"/>
<input type="hidden" name="language[]" id="language" value="PHP"/>PHP 
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" id="price" value="400"> <br/>

4<input type="checkbox" name="count[]" id="count[]" value="4"/>
<input type="hidden" name="language[]" id="language" value="PHP"/>PHP 
<input type="hidden" name="price[]" id="price" value="400"> <br/>

<input type="submit" name="sbt" id="sbt" value="SUBMIT">
```

This is PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['sbt'])){ <br/>
  $count = $_POST['count']; <br/>
  $sub_menu = $_POST['sub_menu']; <br/>
  $sub_price = $_POST['sub_price']; <br/>

foreach($count as $j)

   echo $sub_menu[$j] . '['.$sub_price[$j]. ']' ;<br/>
}<br/>
?>
```

How to calculate the sum - total price of checked checkboxes?

for example : result should be displayed like:

Total Price of Selected Programming Languages : 
C++,Java = 1200$

Comment: Based on the checked checkboxes you could check on the server what the price is instead of also send the price on the form. Someone could change the price on that form and send another price.

Answer (score 0):

Since price is getting submitted as an array you can calculate totals like this:

```
$totals = 0;
foreach ($_POST['price'] as $value) {
    $totals += (int)$value;
}
echo 'Total Price of Selected Programming Languages :', implode(',', $_POST['language']), ' = ', $totals, '$';
```

If you want to group totals by language:

```
$prices = [];
foreach ($_POST['price'] as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($prices[$_POST['language']])) {
        $prices[$_POST['language']] = (int)$value;
    }
    else {
        $prices[$_POST['language']] += (int)$value;
    }
}
```

Then you can loop through this new array and output total numbers by language:

```
echo 'Total Price of Selected Programming Languages ';
foreach($prices as $language => $total) {
    echo "{$language}: {$total}, ";
}
```

Comment: I think it should be ``$total_price += (int)$value;``